# Windows Phone: possible to open URLs with :port?

Tags: windows, mobile

I am trying to open a node.js application on my Nokia Lumia 820 (WP8). When I enter the address in the browser (mydomain.net:8088) I get an error:

> "Internet Explorer Mobile doesn't support this type of address and can't display this page".

Is there a workaround or something to get WP8 opening that URL?! I don't really want to use a reverse proxy since I'm trying to test a websocket application running on that port.

Comment: maybe you simply forgot the "http://" prefix for your URL "mydomain.net:8088"?

Comment: +1 but that sucks. It's a browser URL - it should be able to work it out you'd think.

Comment: @UweKeim Why not add a proper answer and pick-up the points!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(As [suggested by Luke Puplett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256957/windows-phone-possible-to-open-urls-with-port/23133198#comment35367449_14256957), here is my answer)*

My assumption is that you simply forgot to specify the protocol. So instead of typing

```
mydomain.net:8088
```

I would recommend to try using

```
http://mydomain.net:8088
```

So that the browser knows how to interpret the `:` before the "8088" (i.e. as a port separator, not as a protocol separator).