# How to open a URL containing a port on Windows Phone?

Tags: internet-explorer, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, port

Opening a link like http://portquiz.net:8080/ results in the following error message on Windows Phone's Internet Explorer:
`We're having trouble displaying this page.`

Happens both on Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1. How can I go to a website that contains a port number as port of its URL? The question at [Windows Phone: possible to open URLs with :port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256957/windows-phone-possible-to-open-urls-with-port) suggests that its enough to include the `http://` prefix, but that does not help in my case.

Comment: I always use this in my home network and I can confirm that this work. Maybe the problem is from the server. Did you check if the url works from another terminal like your computer?

Comment: You're right. It was a network firewall problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm that URLs with ports **do work**. This has been known for a while, and one of the great examples that actually uses this capability to install a third-party test certificate [is Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/monitorwindowsphone7).